# Problem about usage of "this" keyword in C++

Tags: c++

```
class Monitor
{
private:
    int rate;

    Monitor(int rate)
    {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
}
```

This is my code. I try to set the private member "rate" with local member that passes through constructor "rate". But I could use it like that In C#.

The error is:

expression must have class type

Comment: `this` is a pointer.  `this->` is what you want

Comment: so I must use Monitor::rate = rate? Are there any other ways?

Comment: @Anycorn: That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Is the using pointer this-> same thing with using Monitor::rate or Are they different concepts?

Comment: @user: They are different, you can use `Monitor::rate` only if `rate` is a `static` member variable.

Comment: thank you. By the way thanks everyone for your comments and answers.

Comment: AS @Anycorn indicated, In c# "this" is a reference: "this.AnyField = 5;", in C++ is a pointer: "this->AnyField = 5;".

Comment: @Naveen: `Monitor::rate` can also be used in a member function to mean the non-static member, and is equivalent to `this->rate`.

Comment: In general having an argument with the same name as a data member is bad idea. However, some projects require the use of the exact same name for an argument and member in the special case of a constructor or a setter when the argument is directly used to set the member. Not my preference, not my rule, but this style is out there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`this` is a pointer, as others have said, but it's much better and more correct to use the base initializer list:

```
class Monitor
{
   int rate;
public:
   Monitor(int rate) : rate(rate) { }
};
```

That way, `Monitor::rate` gets *initialized* to the right value, rather than first default-initalized and then assigned. For more general member objects this may in fact be the only legitimate way to initialize them.

Comment: This is more elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know we had a way like that to do. But, I don't get why we can't cut it with like that
Monitor(int rate) : rate(rate);

Comment: @user810576: You still have to define the body of the constructor, even if it isn't doing anything, so our body is just `{ }`. The base initializer list is part of the definition, not the declaration.

Comment: Take a note that some compilers will warn you about shadowing a parameter

Comment: @VJo: Thanks. Indeed, I would usually write `Monitor(int r) : rate(r) {}`, or if the member is private and decorated, something like `Monitor(int rate) : m_rate(rate) { }` etc. Good call, especially if you want to reuse the parameter: `Foo(Bar a, Car b) : m_a(a), m_b(m_a) { }`.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Monitor
{
private:
    int rate;

    Monitor(int rate)
    {
        this->rate = rate;
    }
}
```

this needs to be treated like a pointer.  Hence the ->

Answer (score 3):

When you refer to `this`, you're accessing a pointer to the object. What you want to do is:

```
Monitor(int rate)
{
    this->rate = rate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` keyword represent a pointer to the current object.
You have to write:

```
this->rate = rate;
```

Dot notation is used if you have a instance of the class.

Answer (score 2):

```
Monitor(int r)
    {
        rate = r;
    }
```

Or better still:

```
Monitor(int r): rate(r)
    {}
```

Answer (score 1):

this->rate = rate.  Pointers use the -> operator in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Since *this* is a pointer to self, then you must use it as such. This fixes your problem :

```
class Monitor
{
private:
    int rate;

    Monitor(int rate)
    {
        this->rate = rate; // this is a pointer
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it is perfectly legal C++ code, one should not use same names for argument(s) and member(s) of a class. Better implementation would be:

```
    class Monitor
    {
    private:    
         int Rate;     // Or m_nRate
    public:
          Monitor(int rate /* OR nRate */) : Rate(rate) /* m_nRate(nRate);*/

          // OR
          Monitor(int rate /* OR nRate */)
          {
              Rate = rate; // this->Rate = rate;     // this->m_nRate = nRate;
          }
      };
```

Comment: Not a downvote, just an IMHO yech. Most coding standards say *not* to use InitialCaps names for members. InitialCaps is typically used for classes. Re the alternative `m_nRate`: Again a personal preference, but I truly despise Hungarian notation. Well, not quite a personal preference; lots and lots and lots of people truly despise Hungarian notation.

Comment: So, what would you have used? 'rate', 'nRate', '_Rate' ? I'm just asking opinion.

Comment: For the data member, 'rate' -- or maybe something more descriptive such as 'update_rate'. Or maybe 'update_interval' since a lot of people misuse the term "rate" (units are something/time) when they mean "interval" (units are time/something). For the constructor or setter, depends on the project coding standards. It's usually out of my hands. The argument name is either exactly the same as that of the data member, or something like "rate_in". The argument is a dummy variable, so giving that precedence over the data member is to me a matter of putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: Let someone use Hungarian notation! :)